# Inverse image$f^{-1}(\{-9\})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I need help, because I have no idea how to solve this.

$$
\text{there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x²$}\\
\text{Determine $f^{-1}(\{-9\})$}
$$

I have no idea how to solve this. Any help is welcome.

I think this has no solution, because $x²\not= -9$, but my friend showed me some solution, but I simply don't understand it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nothing squares to $-9$ as you say so the preimage is the empty set.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** $x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in A$.

Comment: One question: X is a set, and x is a element of the set X. Is this right???

Comment: @depecheSoul he likely means $f(x)$ not $f(X)$...

Comment: Yes, thanks, @gt6989b and depecheSoul.

Comment: +1 Short but effective. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @B.S.: Well, number theory is not my forte... but you can try, I guess?

Comment: @B.S. Gee, that's a tough cookie. Short of going through all the elements in the set, and picking a representative from each equivalence class (which is $O(n^2)$), I don't know any other method.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The preimage $f^{-1}(-9)$ consists of the first coordinate of the intersection points of the parabola $f(x)=x^2$, with the horizontal line $g(x)=-9$. Can you draw an image?

Answer (score 2):

What $f^{-1}(S)$ means is the set of elements $x$ such that $f(x)$ is in $S$.

That is, the answer is a set, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there are no real numbers $x$ for which $x^2=-9$.

The notation $f^{-1}$ is a little dodgy. Notice that there are two numbers that square to give $4$. We have $(-2)^2=4$ and $(+2)^2=4$. This makes $f^{-1}$ a [multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function) since $f^{-1}(4) = \pm 2$.

In general, you have to extend your thinking to the [complex numbers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_numbers). We have $\operatorname{i}^2=-1$ and so $$(\pm 3\operatorname{i})^2 = -9$$.

Comment: $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, so $\pm 3i$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @MJD Did you actually read my post?

Comment: I did, and I have now read it twice.

Comment: @MJD Your downvote is misplaced. They should be reserved for unuseful answers. An answer that say "there are no solutions over the real numbers. You would need complex numbers to solve your problem" is not unuseful.

Comment: Please do not assume that I downvoted your post just because I left a comment about it.

Comment: @MJD It's a bit of a coincidence. You call my post irrelevant and then it's down voted. Perhaps it is a split-second coincidence. If so then I apologise.